# json unexpected token error on a json string generated by json_encode()

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I'm having trouble with ajax/json

Php `json_encode()` generated this json code:

```
[{"createdDate":"2013-08-16 13:23:35","body":"kpk"},
{"createdDate":"2013-08-16 13:20:18","body":"iji"},
{"createdDate":"2013-08-16 13:17:34","body":"kp"},
{"createdDate":"2013-08-16 13:17:16","body":"kp"},
{"createdDate":"2013-08-16 13:15:11","body":"koml"},
{"createdDate":"2013-08-16 13:14:08","body":"lplpp,"},
{"createdDate":"2013-08-16 13:13:59","body":"lplpp,"},
{"createdDate":"2013-08-16 13:10:51","body":"mpmkp"},
{"createdDate":"2013-08-16 13:10:29","body":"ook"},
{"createdDate":"2013-08-16 13:07:48","body":"oomoloo"}]
```

but I keep on getting unexpected token error, can anyone explain to me why ?

The error is thrown when I try to parse the json string
in the following way:

```
function ajax_callback(mex)  
{
   mexx = JSON.parse(mex); 
   //other stuff
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you post the code that is throwing the error

Comment: Because the way you are injecting this into JavaScript code is wrong. If you show us the (PHP) code that does something with the output of `json_encode` it will be apparent.

Comment: and what is your error?

Comment: I input this code at the following validator and it also thrws an error http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @user986437: No it doesn't.

Comment: No the JSON is properly formed.

Comment: @user986437 Valid JSON by jsonlint.com

Comment: Paste codes that you getting error. while `json_decode()`?

Answer (score 0):

Either your `mex` variable is not correct;

OR

You are not using the variable `mexx` correctly, note that `mexx` will be resulted to an array so you have to use it like this: `mexx[0].body`

Since, the JSON is correct. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dws5d/)